# When is binding created in code behind removed

Tags: wpf

I have wpf application and I´m creating binding for my control in code behind. The control is added to visual tree and removed from visual tree also in code behind.

It is also necessary to remove this binding in code behind or it will be removed automatically when the control is removed from visual tree?

I have read documentation on MSDN but there is no mention about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't have the binding rooted to somewhere than it will be garbage collected. Xaml is just syntactic sugar over CLR objects.

If you create a binding, and keep a reference to it in some other class, it will not get garbage collected. But if you are just creating the binding, and not keeping a reference to it anywhere, than it will be garbage collected once the Source and Target fall out of Scope.